# Cannot find module 'react' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite

I attempting to create a react app using typescript, but all the imported modules are bright red.

[image]

[image]

I tried to install the module and its type definitions by running the command `npm install react` and `npm i --save-dev @types/react` to solve the error. But it doesn't work. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Does your app run / build ok? If so, it's just a problem with your editor (VSCode). Try restarting it

Comment: My run / build ok. And I tried restarting it, but it wasn't resolved.

Comment: You should conider using create-react-app with a typescript template.